# toggleClass removes all other existing classes

Tags: jquery, intersection-observer

My goal is to add/replace new classes to `body`, dynamically provided by the "id" variable below. That variable's value is the actual `id` of each `section` that passes into the viewport on scroll. So as different `sections` (obviously with different `ids`) pass through the viewport, they pass their `id` name to the `body` as a new `class`, adding a new or replacing the previous `class`. Using `toggleClass` with the boolean `true`, it works, but it's *also* replacing all of the other classes on the `body` tag, given inherently by the Wordpress template, which of course is breaking everything else. Make sense? Any insights would be helpful.

```
var id = entry.target.getAttribute('id');

var newClass = $('body').toggleClass(id, true);
```

Comment: why not simply do `$('body').removeClass(id);` ?

Comment: Thanks. The goal is to have the class be dynamically replaced by the value of the id variable (the id name) so I can apply different styles to the body. The context is that I'm using an Intersection Observer to determine when sections of the page (with different ids) enter the viewport, pass the id name to the body tag as a class when they do and then replace the new body class with another when another section enters the viewport.

Comment: so is `id` giving you correct value ? what doesn't work here ?

Comment: Everything is working except `toggleClass` is removing all the other classes attached to the `body` tag by Wordpress and replacing all of them with my desired classes (provided by the id variable).

Comment: did you tried like this `$('body').removeClass(id);` ?

Comment: its not clear, you want. with the command `$('body').toggleClass(id, true);`you add your class in all tags in body. if you dont want this, you have to give the rule which avoid to add the class for the tags desired.. and when you say: `It's working but also removing all the other 50+ classes attached` its not right, the command dont remove the classes already included before the command; it add the new class.(swith `true`)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass the class name you want to toggle only

```js
$('div').toggleClass('c3');
```

```css
.c1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.c3 {
  color: red;
}

.c2 {
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="c1 c2 c3">TEST</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but the class name is dynamically generated by the variable "id". I should've been more explicit.

Comment: @pjldesign you should add an example for that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select (i dont know your rules) what part of your body have to add the class desired: you could enumerate all tags of your body like this:

```
console.log("there are " + $('body *').length + " tags in the body");
  

$('body *').each(function(){
  // here its an example of data you could access
  // you could test following your condition and modify or not the class corresponding
  console.log("tag: " + $(this).prop("tagName"));//display the tag
  console.log("class: " + $(this).attr("class")); //display the class or undefined
  console.log("content: " + $(this).html());      //display the content of tag
});
```